Intuition for method of characteristics for first order PDEs
Background: I just started learning my very first PDEs and this is my first method I encountered and I have some questions regarding the use of the characteristic method. This is a basic question but it's important for me to understand and hope someone clears it up.
Take for example:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=1$$
The solution sketch for $u(x,y)$ is:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{a}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{b}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{c}}=1,$$ where $a=b=c=1$ in this case.
Now here we take two equations $1)$ $dx=dy$ $2)$ $dx=du$ and then integrate them respectively to get for $1)$ $x=y+F_1$ and $2)$ $u=x+F_2$.
Then we rearrange those to get $F_1, F_2$ and after putting in $\varphi(x-y,u-x)=0$. Using fact that $F_2=g(F_1)$, where $g$ is arbitrary function, $u-x=g\left(x-y\right)\quad\Rightarrow\quad u=x+g\left(x-y\right)$
After seeing many other examples, I see mostly the same steps (sometimes $g(F_2)=F_1$ though).
My questions are:

Why/do we always take $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}$ for $1)$ and? $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{du}{c}$ for $2)$, whenever we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}a=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}b=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{c}$? Can I take it in other order, e.g., for $2)$ to have $\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{c}$?
How do we know what to leave in LHS after integrating $1)$ and $2)$? For $1)$, why it's here $x=y+F_1$, not $y=x+F_1$?
Why/when $F_2=g(F_1)$, when $g(F_2)=F_1$?

These questions come from a broader question: would it change the validity of solution if I did something differently as outlined in my questions 1-3, i.e., is solution $u=g(y-x)+x$ equivalently valid as $u=x+g\left(x-y\right)$ is?

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{a}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{b}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{c}}=1\quad\text{is FALSE}$$ The left term is an infinitesimal cannot be equal to the right trerm which is a finite number. You are allowed to write : $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{a}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{b}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{c}}=ds$$ as used in some context of parametrisation.


We don't always take those two pairings. Yes, you can use $dy/b = du/c$ instead 2. It's just two different ways of looking at the same thing. You can use either $x = y + F_{1}$ or $y = x + F_{1}$, $F_{1}$ is just an integration constant. 3. Again, it's just two different ways of looking at the same thing, you can use either approach. 4. Those solutions are exactly the same, differentiate them to see that they satisfy the PDE.


Thank you guys!

This section, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation, and its subsections, casting the process as finding the tangents to a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ might provide some useful intuition.
